# Java Swing: Separating the GUI of each screen into separate files/classes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cardlayout, jlayeredpane

I'm still a newbie in Java Swing, which we have been learning for a class, and I'm doing this for a small project.

So this is kind of what the GUI is like [without the specifications and design] when cramped in 1 java file. However, my file has become extremely messy due to the length of the code, and there were a lot of unnecessary variable names since I could not use the same variable name again for each screen. I've been learning Java Swing for 3 months in school, but I've only encountered this problem now. I want to know how to separate the GUI files (i.e. Screen1GUI.java, Screen2GUI.java, Screen3GUI.java,...) but sadly, we never tackled it, and I can't seem to find the right words to search it online.

```
public JLayeredPane layeredPane;
private JPanel Screen1, Screen2, Screen3;
private JButton switch1, switch2;

public MainGUI() {
    // other code

    Screen1 = new JPanel();
    // Screen1 GUI
    layeredPane.add(Screen1, "Screen 1");
    switch.addActionListener((ActionEvent a) -> {
       switchScreens(Screen2);
    });
    Screen1.add(switch1);

    Screen2 = new JPanel();
    // Screen2 GUI
    layeredPane.add(Screen2, "Screen 2");
    switch2.addActionListener((ActionEvent b) -> {
       switchScreens(Screen3);
    });
    Screen2.add(switch2);
    
    Screen3 = new JPanel();
    // Screen3 GUI
    layeredPane.add(Screen3, "Screen 3");
    
    CardLayout screens = (CardLayout) layeredPane.getLayout();
    screens.show(layeredPane, "Screen 1");

    // other code
}

public void switchScreens(JPanel screen) {
    layeredPane.removeAll();
    layeredPane.add(screen);
    layeredPane.repaint();
    layeredPane.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score -1):

To separate each swing object into it's own class you should be able to simply create a new class that extends JPanel e.g.

```
public class Screen1GUI extends JPanel {
    public Screen1GUI(){
        super();
    }
}
```

To make it even more organized you can probably abstract the class to take into account similar properties such as the Screen name and the switch button

```java
public class Screen extends JPanel {
    
    private JButton switchButton;
    private String title;

    public Screen(){
        super();
    }
    
    public Screen(String title){
        this();
        this.title=title;
    }

    public void setNext(JPanel next){
        if(switchButton!=null){
                this.remove(switchButton);
        }
        if(next!=null){
            switchButton=new Button("next");
            switchButton.addActionListener(e->switchScreens(next));
        }
     }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    private void switchScreens(JPanel panel){
        Component parent = getParent();   
        parent.removeAll();
        parent.add(screen);
        parent.repaint();
        parent.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Then in your MainGUI method

```java
Screen Screen1;
Screen Screen2;
Screen Screen3;
JLayeredPane layeredPane;
public void MainGUI(){
   Screen1 = new Screen("Screen1");
   Screen2 = new Screen("Screen2");
   Screen3 = new Screen("Screen3");
   Screen1.setNext(Screen2);
   Screen2.setNext(Screen3);
   addAll(Screen1,Screen2,Screen3);
}
public void addAll(Screen...screens){
    for(Screen screen : screens){
        layeredPane.add(screen,screen.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: Minus one. 1) Don't mix Swing and AWT components. 2) Don't extend when a plain instance will suffice. 3) A `CardLayout` (as mentioned above) is the best way to swap panels.

Comment: I was answering what this user wanted to know, which was 'how to separate each screen into certain separate classes'. While I agree proper API usage and best practices should be integral to all development, missed fundamentals such as inheritance, make that very hard to accomplish.